# install window service after authentication

Tags: c#

i created a window service in c#. Now i want to install that service but before installing it, i want a window form where client enters the product key to install the service. if he enters the correct key then installs the service on client's system.
In short, i want to install a window service with window form application.
For this i created a solution and added 2 projects(window service and window form application) into it. now how can i install window service by window application.

i am new in c#. please help me how can i achieve this.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: how can i show you? i am so sorry. i couldn't get your point.

  private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string key = p_key.Text;

            if (key == "string")
            {
              // install servic
            }
            else
            {
                Form2 frm = new Form2("failure");
                frm.Show();
            }
        }

Comment: Rinav means normally on SO you're expected to show you made some effort to research and solve the problem yourself. Normally you don't get many (or good quality) answers from people if it looks like you're just asking for people's time without at least trying it yourself. So, if you made some attempt at implementing this feature, then show your code and explain what part isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, you are looking for installing windows service from application. Try something like that;

```
    public void InstallWindowsService(string servicePath)
    {
        var isElevated = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        if (isElevated)
        {
            ExecuteCommand("cmd.exe", string.Format("{0} {1}", InstallUtilArguments(), servicePath));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("You should run the application as Administrator.");
        }
    }

    private string InstallUtilArguments()
    {
        string framework = @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe";

        if (8 == IntPtr.Size || (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432"))))// for 64 bit Windows OS
        {
            framework = @"\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\installutil.exe";
        }

        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + framework;
    }
    private string ExecuteCommand(string fileName, string arguments)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = fileName,
            Arguments = arguments,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
        };

        using (Process proc = new Process())
        {
            proc.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
            proc.Start();

            string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
            {
                output = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            }

            return output;
        }
    }
```

Detect that is user which run the application elevated, Determine operating system (64 bit or 32 bit), Build `InstallUtil` arguments,  and execute it with `cmd.exe`

Usage;

```
InstallWindowsService(@"C:\YourService\YourService.exe");
```

Comment: but the user can still install widow service without entering product key without going through window form application. can i restrict user? that he can install window service after entering the product key.

Comment: Anybody is here can't provide your complete code. I provide an example about installing windows service. You should implement it after validating your product license or something else.